# How do I add multiple pictures from database to a report "detail"?

Tags: mysql, image, ireport

I'm building a report in iReport so I can generate PDFs from my db data. Along with my "description" field I have multiple images which I'd like to display in the detail band. The amount of pictures depends on the exact report I'm generating the PDF for. What is the best approach for display these images? I'd like them displayed one under the other with their appropriate captions. The filename/locations are store in a "pictures" table along with the captions. I assume I need a subreport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **imageExpression** property to managing *WHAT* picture to display. For example:

```
        <parameter name="whatImageToShow" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="true">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf(1)]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        ...
        <image>
            <reportElement x="0" y="296" width="270" height="65"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{whatImageToShow}.intValue() == 0 ? "image1.jpg" : "image2.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

With help of **printWhenExpression** property you can manage *WHEN* you need to show image. For example:

```
        <parameter name="toShowPicture" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="true">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        ...
        <image>
            <reportElement x="0" y="296" width="270" height="65">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{toShowPicture}.booleanValue()]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{whatImageToShow}.intValue() == 0 ? "image3.jpg" : "image4.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

> The filename/locations are store in a "pictures" table along with the
>   captions. I assume I need a subreport?

Yes, you cannot use several queries (datasources) in one report. And yes, you need a subreport.
You can return data from subreport to master data. You can view sample report at $IREPORT_HOME$\ireport\samples\Subreports folder and read this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7348408/876298).

**UPDATED:**
I've just found useful as I think article [Creating jasper reports with dynamic images](http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/inserting-images-from-database-into-jasper-reports/). May be it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! This tutorial will be very helpful!