# Returning a value from Sub Report to Main Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348408/returning-a-value-from-sub-report-to-main-report-in-ireport) thread to try returning the values `metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1` and `metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1` from sub report to main report, but the only value I get is null. My JRXML files are found below:

**Main Report**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report7" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fd6ce9ca-1ecb-4541-b6b2-446f4da339de">
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/SAW/Database/report7"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://172.16.230.131:8081/jasperserver/ser vices/repository"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/Users/mjohansson/Downloads/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ParameterMainReport" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
    'collectionName':'benchmark',
    sort:{productivityAndProcessMetrics.operationalCost.overallCost:-1}
}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="systemID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="productivityAndProcessMetrics.operationalCost.overallCost" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <variable name="metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="None" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="None" calculation="System"/>
    <title>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="248b1d82-f1a8-4a3e-8fab-58ed34517b9c" x="0" y="0" width="175" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[System ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a2b5c406-76a0-4ffa-b84f-fcf17d43a768" x="275" y="0" width="125" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[LOC]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="26c40738-a9c9-4e3a-8f32-2d69f38be204" x="175" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[MaintenanceCost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="2cca751f-1ffa-4c6e-855c-24c5bf4a9b3f" x="400" y="0" width="125" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Maintainability]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="1510b437-bfe1-4610-aeea-78c24d5f0c42" x="0" y="1" width="175" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression>    <![CDATA[($F{productivityAndProcessMetrics.operationalCost.overallCost}!=null)?$F{systemID}:""]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="2252d608-802e-442f-a3ee-07619e955640" x="275" y="1" width="250" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
            <subreportParameter name="SystemID">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[($F{productivityAndProcessMetrics.operationalCost.overallCost}!=null)?$F{systemID}:null]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="ParameterSubReport">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ParameterMainReport}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1" toVariable="metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1"/>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1" toVariable="metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1"/>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:report7_subreport1.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="d81f0296-7dff-4cdc-9d48-ec477154fc0e" x="175" y="1" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productivityAndProcessMetrics.operationalCost.overallCost}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="4c995889-51aa-42db-8e44-ef169372330c" x="525" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="fb61c381-1862-4817-a7ad-23f24d142e6a" x="625" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Sub Report**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report7_subreport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="250" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="250" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="3ec7fa69-029a-4882-8308-8496807fe30d">
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/SAW/Database/report7"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://172.16.230.131:8081/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
    <parameter name="ParameterSubReport" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SystemID" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
    'collectionName':'systemMetrics',
    'findQueryRegEx':{lang:'/^ALL_LANGUAGES_AGGREGATE/' ,sysID:'/^$P!{SystemID}/'}
}]]></queryString>
    <field name="metrics.LINES_OF_CODE" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="metrics.MAINTAINABILITY" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="sysID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{metrics.LINES_OF_CODE}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{metrics.MAINTAINABILITY}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="20">
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="48938680-a5b7-4d16-b3e0-79e02a43336c" x="0" y="0" width="125" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{metrics.LINES_OF_CODE_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="59f69b58-fd5c-44a8-abdd-410e30d48627" x="125" y="0" width="125" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{metrics.MAINTAINABILITY_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any input would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returned value from subeport to main report is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384421/returned-value-from-subeport-to-main-report-is-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my-self by setting the evaluation time on the field calling my output variable from "Now" to "Auto".

Answer (score 0):

For people who can not change evaluation time (because they whan to pass the variable as a parameter to another subreport for exemple) :

**Do not use the variable returnes in the same band than the subreport himself !**

The affectation is done I think at the end of the rendering of the band...

So ----> "*add another band*" and use your variable inside ;)

Hope this can help, I took me hours to discover this !