# How to get return value from sub report to main report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* 4.5.1 version i am facing problem with sum of value,  i have two report one is main report and another is sub-report main report has 3 row and sub report have 5 row and 3 column  i want to do the last column's sum and pass to the main report. so i am create one variable and store the  sum of column no 3 and return it to main report but every time i am getting first total is null or 0 and i am not getting last table's total  like this

```
 This is my main report
-----------------------------------------------------
    no     Item               price        discount%
-----------------------------------------------------
 This is my Sub-Report
    1         A                 150              10
    2         B                 200              10
    3         C                 550              25
 ---------------------------------------------------
 This is also my Main report
   Total                       Sum(Prise)

-----------------------------------------------------
    no     Item               price        discount%
-----------------------------------------------------
    1         A                 1150              10
    2         B                 2500              5
 ---------------------------------------------------
   Total                       Sum(Prise)  

-----------------------------------------------------
    no     Item               price        discount%
-----------------------------------------------------
    1         A                 50000              10
    2         B                 20500              5
 ---------------------------------------------------
   Total                       Sum(Prise)
```

i am getting the out put is Sum1= null,  sum2==(150+200+550) and sum3 =(1150+2500) and i am getting the third tables sum.

how can i solve it please help me .

Comment: You are not giving us any information on how are you actually retrieving the sum value from the subreport to the main one. However, check these links for some details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348408/returning-a-value-from-sub-report-to-main-report-in-ireport , http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534659/how-return-value-subreport , http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports

Comment: I solved this query thanks thanks