# JasperReport how sum values of an sub report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this structure of my report:

```
MAIN
    DETAIL   
        SUB
            DETAIL 1 { date of travel }
            DETAIL 2 { table of orders of date of travel
                TABLE { 
                    HEADER
                    ROWS
                    FOORTER { SUMMARY VALUES } <- i need sum this
                }

            }
            DETAIL 3 { table of spendings of date of travel
                TABLE {
                        HEADER
                        ROWS
                        FOORTER { SUMMARY VALUES } <- i need sum this 
                }
            }
    SUMMARY 
        total : sum of summary values of orders
        total : sum of summary valyes of spendings
```

I have 3 detail bands in my sub report. So.. I need SUM ALL summary of orders and spendings of my travel and print this in MAIN SUMMARY BAND. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to total the amount in each subreport and then return the values to 3 prams. In the main report then sum them.

[Returning a value from Sub Report to Main Report in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348408/returning-a-value-from-sub-report-to-main-report-in-ireport)